# include an php file with included files

Tags: php, include

Here is directory structure

- /global.php
- /includes/class_bootstrap.php
- /includes/init.php
- /plugins/myplugin.php

### Here is codes in these files

**/start.php**

```
require('./includes/class_bootstrap.php');
```

**/includes/class_bootstrap.php**

```
define('CWD', (($getcwd = getcwd()) ? $getcwd : '.'));
require_once(CWD . '/includes/init.php');
```

**/plugins/myplugin.php**

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'../global.php');
```

And as far as I am understanding the problem is in class_bootstrap.php file coz it's generating wrong path for CWD
here is error:

> Warning: require_once(C:/wamp/www/vb4/plugins/includes/init.php) [function.require-once]:
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:/wamp/www/vb4/global.php on line 35

As you can see "C:/wamp/www/vb4/plugins/includes/init.php" is wrong path.

The MAIN PROBLEM is that I can edit only myplugin.php file other files are CMS core files and should not be changed.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you need to determine the base path of a set of scripts, you *should not* rely on the "current working directory."  This can change from executing environment to executing environment.

Instead, base it on a known path.

`/includes/class_bootstrap.php` *knows* that it's going to be one directory down from where the base path is going to be, so it can do this:

```
define('CWD', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../') );
```

[`dirname`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php) gets the directory name given in the passed string.  If `__FILE__` returns `C:/wamp/www/vb4/plugins/includes/class_bootstrap.php`, then `dirname` will return `C:/wamp/www/vb4/plugins/includes`.  We then append `/../` to it and then call [`realpath`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php), which turns that relative `..` into a real directory: `C:/wamp/www/vb4/plugins`

Phew.

From that point forward, `CWD` will operate as you expect.  You can `require_once CWD . '/includes/init.php'` and it will correctly resolve to `C:/wamp/www/vb4/plugins/includes/init.php`

Also, this may sound stupid but "vb4" may be referring to vBulletin 4, in which case your plugin *may* already have access to the configuration information that it exposes, including handy things like paths.  This may make this entire exercise unnecessary.  I intentionally know nothing about vB, otherwise I would point you at their dev docs.

Comment: /plugins/myplugin.php file is separate file and I want connect with CMS functions and vars including global.php

Comment: As I've stated -- the code in `/includes/class_bootstrap.php` is **wrong**.  You must correct it to *not* use `getcwd()` in order for it to function properly.  `getcwd()` is *not* a reliable way to determine *file paths* -- as you've found, it can change to unexpected values.  If that code is not yours, so be it -- change it anyway to get things working, and **file a bug report with the upstream code provider**.  (And if it *is* vB, I'm entirely unsurprised that they'd do something as ... unthinking ... as this.)

Comment: Thanks Charles, Yes I'd like edit class_bootstrap.php file but It will not be good future for my plugin, yes sure I'm going to make bug report.

Comment: chdir() would help but I'd hate it :)

Comment: Yeah, `chdir` gets lumped into my list of "if you're using it, something's probably *wrong*" functions.

Comment: Yes lol chdir helps, Thanks guys!
chdir('/vb4/');
include './global.php';