# include file within an included file

Tags: php

This is my directory:

```
global.php
includes
    class_bootstrap.php
resourcemanager
    index.php
```

To include global.php in the file index.php, I have:

```
require_once('../global.php');
```

And in global.php, i have:

```
require_once(./includes/class_bootstrap.php);
```

When run index.php, i got this message:

> Warning: require_once(./includes/class_bootstrap.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\yurivn\global.php on line 15
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required './includes/class_bootstrap.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\yurivn\global.php on line 15

I wonder if PHP search in wrong directory for the file class_bootstrap.php, it may search for **"resourcemanager/includes/class_bootstrap.php"** instead of **"includes/class_bootstrap.php"** because if I put **index.php** to the same directory with **global.php**, it works perfectly.

Is there anyway to make **index.php** work in resourcemanager directory without changing anything in **global.php** or **class_bootstrap.php**? I just writing some plugin, I don't want to change anything belong to the developer.

Comment: Is this the full error message as I remember that after "No such file or directory" there was the full path that was used.

Comment: Sorry, I just edited my question.

Comment: Try use `dirname(__FILE__)` or check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5610248/include-an-php-file-with-included-files

Comment: Relative includes are __not__ relative to the file they're included from: they're relative to the include_path, and (if the include_path contains an entry for `.`, then relative to the current working directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution! Just add this before including:

```
chdir('./../');
```

and include the global.php like they were the same directory:

```
require_once('./global.php');
```

Thank you very much for trying to help me, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 3):

What you really want to do (to make life easier in future) is use a definitions file

As long as this is defined before your code runs then everything will be fine - easiest way is to create a `definitions.php` file and then include this at the top of every page you use.

```
define("URL", "http://yoursite.com/"); //note the trailing / to make life easier.
```

Then on your includes just use

```
require_once(URL . 'file.php');
```

That way on local machine transfer to new host just change the definition or URL to

```
define("URL", "http://siteontheinternet.com/");
```

and you are good to go!

Answer (score 0):

it works if you write full path like

```
include('D:/wamp/www/ajax/a.php');
```

Comment: Is there any other way? It would be annoying when I upload it to my online host, or change my domain.

Comment: @Mee - yes the way I have posted using define will let you do exactly this - refactor your code and be happy :-D

Answer (score 0):

In your `index.php`, try use `dirname(__FILE__)`. So it should be:

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . 'global.php';
```

---

**EDIT**

Since `index.php` is 1 down-level from `global.php`, so you have to add `/../`, so it should be:

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../global.php';
```

Comment: "Is there anyway to make index.php work in resourcemanager directory without changing anything in global.php or class_bootstrap.php? I just writing some plugin, I don't want to change anything belong to the developer." I mentioned it in my question D: Please tell me if it's impossible

Comment: it returns this message "
Warning: require_once(C:\xampp\htdocs\yurivn\resourcemanager/global.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\yurivn\resourcemanager\manga.php on line 4

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\yurivn\resourcemanager/global.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\yurivn\resourcemanager\manga.php on line 4". global.php is in /htdocs/yurivn/, not htdocs/yurivn/resourcemanager

Comment: add `/../`, so: `require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../global.php';`

Comment: Warning: require_once(./includes/class_bootstrap.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\yurivn\global.php on line 14 (Here it is)

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required './includes/class_bootstrap.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\yurivn\global.php on line 14

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
require_once('../includes/class_bootstrap.php');
```

Comment: Well there are many other files at the same directory as global.php requiring it, so I can't change anything in global.php. I mentioned it in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be to set ROOT_DIR in your index or config, and then use that to resolve all other include paths.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below:

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__ . '/../global.php';
```

And on `global.php` file :

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/includes/class_bootstrap.php';
```

Comment: The OP stated that he don't want to change anything in `global.php` or `class_bootstrap.php`